# Screenshot image is not showing for Twitter share on Android device

Tags: android, twitter, lua, coronasdk

I am having this issue which I hope you can help me solve. Basically I have set up twitter sharing on Corona SDK (using the social plugin) so that players can post their highscores. The game would save a JPEG image and then Twitter loads this inside the message when sharing.

Now the issue is that on iOS, this works perfectly, but on Android devices the image doesn't show in the message body. Can you please help me as I have been banging my head trying to figure this out but have gotten nowhere. Cheers.

**Here is my code to take the screenshot:**

```
function takePhoto()
    local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory

    display.save(overlayGroup, "myScreenshot.jpg", baseDir )
    print("PIC SAVED")
end
```

**And this these are the options for sharing:**

```
local options = {
    service = "twitter",
    message = "You got a highscore! ",
    listener = tweetCallback,
    image = {
      baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory,
      filename = "myScreenshot.jpg"
    }
}
```

**And these are the code in build.settings**

```
android =
{
    versionCode = "1",
    googlePlayGamesAppId = "xxxxxxxxxx", --My code is here
    usesPermissions =
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you put the permission in you Build.settings file? "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ?

Comment: Yes I have that set up in the build.settings file. I will add them to the OP so you can see the setup for it.

Comment: Does overlayGroup actually contain the stuff you want screenshotted? Maybe try the new syntax: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/save.html

Comment: Maybe try the ScreenCaptureToFile example app first. Maybe your code isn't the problem. It wouldn't be the first time display.save is bugged on some Android devices.

Comment: Yes the overlayGroup has the right stuff i need. It shows up great on iOS. I will try the ScreenCaptureToFile example and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: its not something as simple as case sensitivity is it? I know android is case sensitive with images...

Comment: Do you set a brief delay before sharing the screenshot? sometimes android needs a few seconds for it to save images.

Comment: also, if it is possible try on other android devices..

Comment: Can you see the image on the device using Photo or other FileViewer?

Comment: I managed to get this to work using a delay before saving the image. Very weird but thanks for the help.